# Multiple random outputs from same pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, spyder, anaconda3

I need to have 3 output variables with values from 1 to x, and I need them all to equal 3+y.

If my variables are called "A, B, C" my code is as follows:

```
A=1
B=1
C=1

while y>0:
    A=A+randint(0,y)
    y=y-A+1
    B=B+randint(0,y)
    y=y-B+1
    C=C+randint(0,y)
    y=y-C+1
```

This had the problem that it doesn't give all 3 outputs a fair chance, and i also have not found a way to check for x.

Any ideas, even incomplete ones will be welcome, thanks a lot.

Comment: Where do you initialize `y`?

Comment: If they should all equal `3+y`, what does this have to do with random values? Just `A=B=C = y+3`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
from random import randrange

def get_ints(y):
    nums = [1, 1, 1]

    # loop y times
    for _ in range(y):
        # iterate a random element
        nums[randrange(3)] += 1
    return nums

# if you want them in A, B, C
A, B, C = get_ints(100)
```

This should be the same result as:

```
from random import choices

def get_ints(y):
    indices = choices(range(3), k=y)
    return [indices.count(i) + 1 for i in range(3)]

A, B, C = get_ints(100)
```

I'm sure there is a way to get this result in constant time though...

It's worth noting that this distribution isn't going to have a lot of variance. If you want that then you should go with a method like:

```
def get_ints(y):
    nums = [randrange(y + 1), randrange(y + 1)]
    A = min(nums) + 1
    B = max(nums) - min(nums) + 1
    C = y - max(nums) + 1
    return A, B, C
```

Comment: Hint, either you use `\`\`\`` without any language indication, and then it picks up the (most prominent?) language from the question tags, or you use `\`\`\` python` including the space separator.